# Estou tentando fazer um PIVOT, mas as colunas pivotadas só apresentam null

Tags: sql-server, null, pivot

Temos uma tabela `socio` em que temos o `cnpj_basico` como chave estrangeira e uma coluna com o nome dos sócios.

Preciso que apareça o `cnpj_basico` e todos seus sócios em uma única linha. Montei o código com `PIVOT`, mas o resultado só retorna `null` para todas as colunas e linhas (pivotadas), sendo que todo cnpj tem pelo menos 1 sócio.

Por favor, alguém consegue me orientar onde está o erro?
Obs: os dados são extraídos de arquivos disponibilizados no site da receita federal (https://dados.gov.br/dados/conjuntos-dados/cadastro-nacional-da-pessoa-jurdica---cnpj).

A seguir tem o código (sql server) e a imagem do resultado:

```sql
Select CNPJ_BASICO, [SOCIO1],[SOCIO2],[SOCIO3],[SOCIO4],[SOCIO5],[SOCIO6],[SOCIO7],[SOCIO8],[SOCIO9],[SOCIO10],[SOCIO11],[SOCIO12],[SOCIO13]
from (
             Select cnpj_basico, NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL, 'NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL' + 
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CNPJ_BASICO ORDER BY sk_teste) AS VARCHAR) AS socio
             FROM SOCIO_RFB
            ) AS a
            PIVOT (
               max(NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL) FOR socio IN([SOCIO1],[SOCIO2],[SOCIO3],[SOCIO4],[SOCIO5],[SOCIO6],[SOCIO7],[SOCIO8],[SOCIO9],[SOCIO10],[SOCIO11],[SOCIO12],[SOCIO13])
                  ) AS p `
```

[imagem do codigo indentado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r19VE.png)

[imagem do resultado do script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnj0B.png)

Comment: Experimente fazer uns testes alterando o trecho onde está `'NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL' +` para `'SOCIO' +`, pois entre parênteses você utilizou [SOCIOn]

Comment: Imex, deu certo!! Muito obrigada!!

Answer (score -2):

Rodei localmente o código aqui, e a função PIVOT falhou com alguns valores nulos.

Tenta adicionar outra coluna no teu ORDER BY da função ROW_NUMBER() para garantir ordenação única.

```
SELECT CNPJ_BASICO, [SOCIO1],[SOCIO2],[SOCIO3],[SOCIO4],[SOCIO5],[SOCIO6],[SOCIO7],[SOCIO8],[SOCIO9],[SOCIO10],[SOCIO11],[SOCIO12],[SOCIO13] 
FROM (
  SELECT CNPJ_BASICO, NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL, 'NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CNPJ_BASICO ORDER BY ID_SOCIO, sk_teste) AS VARCHAR) AS socio
  FROM SOCIO_RFB
) AS cnpj 
PIVOT (
  MAX(NOME_SOCIO_OU_RAZAO_SOCIAL) 
  FOR socio IN([SOCIO1],[SOCIO2],[SOCIO3],[SOCIO4],[SOCIO5],[SOCIO6],[SOCIO7],[SOCIO8],[SOCIO9],[SOCIO10],[SOCIO11],[SOCIO12],[SOCIO13])
) AS pivot
```